# Data connection issues during when working with IoT devices

Tags: mobile-data

Following my previous question [here](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/137/how-cellular-technologies-benefits-for-iot), what are solutions to overcome issues with the data connection (i.e. data out off-quota or I'm out of coverage) during the work with my IoT devices. Especially when working tackling critical issues?

This is focused more on mobile connectivity since I don't want this to be broad and off-topic. I asked this since in my country, Malaysia we quite regularly have the lagging issues compared to the US & other western countries.

Comment: With a question like this, you need to provide a context that the experts in a different native environemet will understand, and using language appropriate to the art. Also, your question should really be more specific (there is no problem with multiple questions). Ask about a single specific data related issue, with a clear application context - otherwise you give the impression of knowing almost nothing about the subject.

Comment: @SeanHoulihane noted. I'll be more study on this. thanks for your support.

Comment: One small tip (by no means an answer) - when developing an app which periodically polls for data, I have the client calculate an MD5 and send that as part of the request.  The server calculates the MD5 of its version of the data and if they match returns an HTTP result code which indicates that there is no new data. Only useful if you develop both client & server, but it can reduce lag when downloading large amounts of data which the client already has, ***and*** it can save money, depending on your data plan.

Comment: thanks @Mawg for this answer. I don't have idea on how to react with this great info now but I'll proceed my research on this things as well. appreciated on your support. =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To begin with, if there are 'data issues', those issues should be taken up with the data service provider for violation of an agreed SLA. Next, there should be a offline data store option in your solution so that, the requirement of gathering data is taken care. If/when data coverage is available, the older data is republished or after a defined window, etc. As a last resort, the offline data could possibly have been downloaded via USB, etc.

Thus, in summary, storing data offline, republishing when online and archival of the collected data is something should be considered in the overall solution.

Comment: when asking this questions, actually I'm stuck in the middle since when I mention about data, I mean the data quota. then I expect something like alternatives for data quota, eg. free radio access but it may restrict to licensing law applied. this quite broad for some of us but this is the only idea playing around on my mind now.

Comment: "those issues should be taken up with the data service provider" - you ***might*** get some help in Singapore. Good luck trying that in Malaysia (or many other countries)